# Setting properties of View in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

I want to set the following properties for an Android View, but in code.

This is the AdView I am trying to replicate:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
mAdView = new AdView(m_Context);
// Sizes BANNER, SMART_BANNER, LARGE_BANNER
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
//mAdView.setAdUnitId(adIdBanner);
mAdView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000); // First byte alpha
mAdView.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mAdView.setLayoutParams(lp);
myLayout.addView(mAdView);
// OR SHOULD IT BE THIS????
//LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//myLayout.addView(mAdView, params);
```

Is this correct?

What about CenterInParent?

Have I done the width and height right so the width is matchparent and the height is wrapcontent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int paddingTop = 5;
float density = m_Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
int padding = (int)(paddingTop * density);


mAdView = new AdView(m_Context);
// Sizes BANNER, SMART_BANNER, LARGE_BANNER
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(adIdBanner);
mAdView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
mAdView.setPadding(0, padding , 0, 0);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
mAdView.setLayoutParams(params);
myLayout.addView(mAdView);
```

Comment: This looks like it has everything I want, but does not seem to work. Everything written here works, ie no exceptions are thrown. However, when I do `adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` then an exception is thrown on the `loadAd()` line. If I do everything else the same, but using the xml declaration of the AdView, then the `loadAd()` line is fine and the google test advert loads. What am I doing wrong? Why does the program appear to not like your dynamic code?

Comment: I have updated the answer. it should work for you now. Also, just try changing this line in the old answer. See if it works. `mAdView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); `

Comment: Thanks, I have marked this as answer. (Please unhash the line `mAdView.setAdUnitId(adIdBanner);` and make sure that line is included as that is what was causing the error - It was my mistake, I hashed it out when I was tinkering.) Both your old answer and new answer worked with `setAdUnitId` included. You could use your `parseColor` or my `0xFF000000` as they produced the same result. Thank you, thank you, thank you. You are a top person.